# why does the www class in unity returns empty www.text only in android but works fine in editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am a unity developer. The problem is the www class in unity return text value in editor but it returns empty text in android.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public string result;
    public Game game;

    IEnumerator Start () 
    {
        WWW www = new WWW ("www.poquere.com/gotchha/createGame2.php?deck=Easy");
        yield return www;
        result = "Output is : " + www.text;
        Debug.Log (result);
    }


    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label (result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if you are getting an error

```
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        Debug.Log(www.error);
```

Source:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-error.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to include "https://" in your URL.
Unity will fix that for you automatically, but on the phone it will get an error.